# Outlook - no permission to send - find out which address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have an email with multiple recipients. Some of them are sending automatic replies, and some of them have left my organization and their email is no longer valid / has been banned from receiving. Outlook nicely tells me this in a message at the top of the email.

[image: Outlook recipients]

If there are only one or two such addresses, Outlook tells me the exact addresses I can't send to. But if there are several addresses like this, it just says "you don't have permission to send to 4 recipients" or "5 recipients are sending automatic replies". How do I find out which ones these are, without trial and error deleting email addresses? (The colour of the names can also indicate them being external email addresses, so that is not enough clue.)

Comment: What if clicking Send? Will you be able to send the message to other recipients except the invalid ones?

Comment: @YukiSun Yes, and I can actually use the returning error messages to determine to whom I couldn't send, but it is not too elegant.